# How much data traffic does participating in Bitcoin mining cause?

Tags: network, bandwidth

I have a limited amount of data included in my internet plan. If I exceed that limit I get charged extra. So, before signing up for Bitcoin, I'd like to know whether Bitcoin mining causes a lot of internet traffic. Does it involve a lot of downloading and uploading throughout the day?

Comment: Will you be solo mining or joining a pool?

Comment: If you make enough from mining you might still make a profit and be able to pay for the extra charges :p

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you use a light wallet like Electrum, definitely not.  But even if you run a full node, it is unlikely.  You could also use a web-based wallet like blockchain.info which would mean that nothing at all is running on your local computer and you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: OP is not asking about running a wallet, but about mining he could probably benefit from knowing statistics on bandwidth utilization.

Answer (score 5):

If you mine with a pool, your actual internet activity will be fairly small.  I just took a look at my network statistics and BFGMiner used 9MBytes down and 11 MBytes up over the previous 24-hour period.

The Bitcoin-Qt application on the other hand maxes out my upload bandwidth since I always seem to get 2-3 peers who want to download the entire 12 GB blockchain from me.  Other than that, the main Bitcoin-Qt network usage occurs when you are receiving or relaying the latest block (blocks are typically 100-400 KBytes).

Since you have limited internet bandwidth, your best bet would be to run a lightweight client such as Electrum or Multibit.  If you are mining in a pool, you don't need a local Bitcoin-Qt.