# How much data traffic does participating in P2Pool mining cause?

Tags: p2pool, bandwidth

In [an earlier question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17356/323) we learned some rough numbers about how much data does regular pool mining use. However, I wonder how much data is typically used when one is mining in a [P2Pool](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/P2Pool)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Greg Maxwell](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/3u9uc3/how_much_data_traffic_does_participating_in/cxd6odh):

> 4.14kB/sec in, 10.7kb/s out; averaged over the last 30 days. 38GB in transfer total.
>
> Significantly less than the full node that goes with it... p2pool used to be fairly large relative to the node; but greater amounts of load on the Bitcoin network have shifted the balance.